# Сочетание "для большей наглядности"

Tags: грамматика

"Для большей наглядности" — правильное сочетание? Или "для большой наглядности"?

Answer (score 1):

Что Вас интересует? Орфография? Для б**О**льшей, но для больш**О**й. Употребление в речи? Честно говоря, второй вариант не слышала, хотя в каком-нибудь контексте, наверное, возможен. Обычно говорят: *для б**о**льшей наглядности*, т.е. чтобы было более наглядно, зримо.